# Go Scheduler who fills the local runqueue of P?

Tags: go, scheduler

Look at this well known image taken from [morsmachine.dk/go-scheduler](http://morsmachine.dk/go-scheduler)

[image]

The gray lists are *local runqueues* of P. If this queue get empty they will be filled with go routines from the *global runqueue*.

The Question is, who fills the *local runqueue* of P?

Scheduler, without synchronisation or every **P** do it for himself (mutex)?

P.S. The article omits this information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of this is taken from [golang.org/src/runtime/proc.go](https://golang.org/src/runtime/proc.go):

Function `schedule` (the scheduler) calls `findrunnable` which attempts to steal a `G` from another `P`. If that fails, it'll return a `G` from the global run queue. That `G` is then executed on the "current" `M`.

In addition, `schedule` checks the global run queue occasionally "for fairness":

```
// Check the global runnable queue once in a while to ensure fairness.
// Otherwise two goroutines can completely occupy the local runqueue
// by constantly respawning each other.
```

In all of that, only one lock is involved, which is `lock(&sched.lock)`.

Comment: ok it means that every M do it, but it didn't fill the local runqueue, It takes just one and execute it. So local runqueue will never filled again after it get empty. And if we have 32 CPU and therefore 32 M's they will be synchronized by a mutex (lock). right?

Comment: The code is a bit hard to read (because it's auto-translated C) but yes, that's how it seems to work.

Comment: the link is dead